# Where does OpenStack Swift store the rings?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage

does anybody know where OpenStack Swift stores the "Rings"? Is there a distributed algorithm or is it just one table somewhere on some of the Storage Nodes with information about all (!) the physical object locations (I cannot believe that because from my understanding of Object Storage, it should scale to Exabytes, and this would need lots of entries in such a table...)?

This page could not help me: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_ring.html

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ring Builder

> The rings are built and managed manually by a utility called the ring-builder. The ring-builder assigns partitions to devices and writes an optimized Python structure **to a gzipped, serialized file on disk for shipping out to the servers.** The server processes just check the modification time of the file occasionally and reload their in-memory copies of the ring structure as needed.

so, it's stored in all servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you were asking the path of ring,gz files it is under /etc/swift by default
Also these ring files are can be updated using the .builder files when swift rebalance is run.